# Solving a ballistic equation through code

Tags: algorithm, math, equation

This seems like an incredibly simple problem to solve, but everything I've found about it has been too complex for me to understand.

I have this basic ballistic equation:

[image: ballistic trajectory]

Given that I know v, g, x and y, how would I go about finding theta? It's very easy to read on paper, but I don't know how this would be done in code.

[EDIT #3:] My try (with input from answers below) is this:

```
gx = g*x
brackets = gx^2 + 2*y*v^2
sqrroot = sqrt( v^4 - g*brackets )

top1 = v^2 + sqrroot
theta1 = atan( top1 / gx )

top2 = v^2 - sqrroot
theta2 = atan( top2 / gx )
```

Comment: That isn't a quadratic equation....

Comment: Break the equation down into small discrete steps.  Solve for gx.  Solve for gx squared.  Solve for 2yv squared.  And so on, until you have theta.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I've added my code as you've described - do you think it is correct? (It's in Lua, formally, but can be read as pseudo as it's a simple language)

Comment: Updated to include. I am wondering how I would know which result to use?

Comment: @MattW It depends on the context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this equation in code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674993/what-is-this-equation-in-code)

Comment: Many languages support a 4 quadrant arctan as in C's `atan2()`.  This may be useful should you expect abs(theta) > pi/2.

Comment: The brackets value is wrong: gx^2 + 2*y*v^2 = g^2*x^2 + 2*y*v^2.  You want g*x^2 + 2*y*v^2.

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring a solution - you have

```
top = v^2 + sqrroot
```

but you also need to do a recalculation with

```
top = v^2 - sqrroot
```

to account for the `±` in your equation.

So:

```
top1 = v^2 + sqrroot
top2 = v^2 - sqrroot

theta1 = atan(top1 / gx)
theta2 = atan(top2 / gx)
```

(I don't know what `equation` is in your code, but I'm assuming you meant `top`)

Comment: I had only produced code for the + equation. I have updated the code in my post with the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

More like this.

```
gx = g*x
brackets = g*x^2 + 2*y*v^2
sqrroot = sqrt( v^4 - g*brackets )
top1 = v^2 + sqrroot
theta1 = atan( top1 / gx )
top2 = v^2 - sqrroot
theta2 = atan( top2 / gx )
```

You have to account for the plus and the minus in your formula.

You calculate the squares before the multiplication.  In some languages, you can calculate g*x^2 by calculating g*x*x.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the arctan method, you can use a quasi newton algorithm.

Comment: I do not know what a quasi newton algorithm is.

Answer (score 0):

In your last line,

```
theta = atan( equation / gx )
```

`equation` is not set. You probably want to substituted `top` for `equation`.

It may also help for you to output each intermediate result (gx, brackets, sqrroot, and top). See if there any unexpected intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

A c solution

```
#include<math.h>

void MattW_f(double *theta_p, double *theta_n, double g, double v, double x, double y) {
  double v2 = v*v;
  double gx = g*x;
  // No check against sqrt(negative number)
  double discriminant = sqrt(v2*v2 - g*(gx*x + 2*y*v2));
  if (theta_p) {
    // atan2() returns -pi to +pi, it is a 4 quadrant arctan.
    *theta_p = atan2(v2 + discriminant, gx);  
    }
  if (theta_n) {
    *theta_n = atan2(v2 - discriminant, gx);
    }
  }
```